# Converting DOCX with custom XML and Structured Document Tags to PDF

Tags: xml, pdf, ms-word, docx

We currently use Ecrion XF Rendering Server to let our web services convert Word documents to PDF. The documents contain custom XML that is bound to Structured Document Tags.

Ecrion's product is the only software we have found that is able to do this, but the quality of the PDFs generated is mediocre. First of all, it renders the documents differently from Word, secondly it often creates zero byte PDFs because of random crashes, thirdly elements from the documents are sometimes missing, for instance tables.

As we need to do the conversion server side, using Office Automation isn't an option. Aspose.Words for .NET creates much better PDF documents, but [still doesn't support binding SDTs to custom XML](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/303083/words-question.aspx).

Does anyone know of any other products that support this?

Comment: Hey there!  Ever end up landing on a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

[docx4j](http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j) has good support for custom XML data binding, if I may say so myself.

Although it is open source Java, a number of people use it in a .NET environment via IKVM.

It also generates PDF output.  The PDF output isn't perfect, but does include tables, and shouldn't include random crashes :-)  Being open source, you could also modify it to address any issues you encounter.